# a better way to draw grid as background

Tags: c, winapi, gdi+, gdi, grid-layout

I want to draw grid as in the below picture.[image]

I know a trick to draw this by draw 6 vertical and horizontal lines instead of 6 x 6 small rectangle.

But if I want to have smaller zoom (zoom for viewing picture), the lines are many. For example, say my view window is of size 800 x 600 and viewing a picture of size 400 x 300 (so zoom in is 2). There will be 400 x 300 rectangle of size 2 x 2 (each rectangle represents a pixel).

If I draw each cell (in a loop, say 400 x 300 times), it is very slow (when I move the window...).
Using the trick solves the problem.

By I am still curious if there is a better way to do this task in winapi, GDI(+). For example, a function like `DrawGrid(HDC hdc, int x, int y, int numOfCellsH, int numOfCellsV)`?

A further question is: If I don't resize, move the window or I don't change the zoom in, the grid won't be changed. So even if I update the picture continuously (capture screen), it is uncessary to redraw the grid. But I use `StretchBlt` and `BitBlt` to capture the screen (to memory DC then hdc of the window), if I didn't redraw the grid in memory DC, then the grid will disappear. Is there a way to make the grid stick there and update the bitmap of the screen capture?

ps: This is not a real issue. Since I want to draw the grid when zoom is not less than 10 (so each cell is of size 10 x 10 or larger). In this case, there will be at most 100 + 100 = 200 lines to draw and it is fast. I am just  curious  if there is a faster way.

Comment: That's still only 700 lines that you need to draw. It's trivial to do that very quickly. Is drawing 700 lines really a problem?

Comment: @David, I have mentioned this is not an issue for me. But don't I have the right to know if there is a better way?

Comment: Actually SO prefers questions that are about real actual problems. I don't think GDI is particularly slow. I doubt you'll do very much better than it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [CreateDIBSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa926298.aspx) this will allow you a pointer so that you can manipulate the R, G, B values rapidly, for example the following creates a 256x256x24 bitmap and paints a Green squares at 64 pixel intervals:

```
BITMAPINFO BI = {0};
BITMAPINFOHEADER &BIH = BI.bmiHeader;
BIH.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
BIH.biBitCount  = 24;
BIH.biWidth     = 256;
BIH.biHeight    = 256;
BIH.biPlanes    = 1;
LPBYTE pBits = NULL;
HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateDIBSection(NULL, &BI, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**) &pBits, NULL, 0);
LPBYTE pDst = pBits;
for (int y = 0; y < 256; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 256; x++)
    {
        BYTE R = 0;
        BYTE G = 0;
        BYTE B = 0;
        if (x % 64 == 0) G = 255;
        if (y % 64 == 0) G = 255;
        *pDst++ = B;
        *pDst++ = G;
        *pDst++ = R;
    }
}
HDC hMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
HGDIOBJ hOld = SelectObject(hMemDC, hBitmap);
BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 256, 256, hMemDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
SelectObject(hMemDC, hOld);
DeleteDC(hMemDC);
DeleteObject(hBitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, the major limiting factors for these kinds of graphics operations are the fill rate and the number of function calls.

The fill rate is how fast the machine can change the pixel values.  In general, blits (copying rectangular areas) are very fast because they're highly optimized and designed to touch memory in a cache friendly order.  But a blit touches all the pixels in that region.  If you're going to overdraw or if most of those pixels don't really need to change, then it's likely more efficient to draw just the pixels you need, even if that's not quite as cache-friendly.

If you're drawing n primitives by making n things, then that *might* be a limiting factor as n gets large, and it could make sense to look for an API call that lets you draw several (or all) of the lines at once.

Your "trick" demonstrates both of these optimizations.  Drawing 20 lines is fewer calls than 100 rectangles, and it touches far fewer pixels.  And as the window grows or your grid size decreases, the lines approach will increase linearly both in number of calls and in pixels touched while the rectangle method will grow as n^2.

I don't think you can do any better when it comes to touching the minimum number of pixels.  But I suppose the number of function calls *might* become a factor if you're drawing very many lines.  I don't know GDI+, but in plain GDI, there are functions like `Polyline` and `PolyPolyline` which will let you draw several lines in one call.